# C# unit test with time delay passes debug but fails on build server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timer

I have a class in ASP.NET core that runs a small task in given intervals using Threading.Timer (because Timer.Timer is not available in Core). Now I wrote a unit test that checks how many time a job is run:

```
[Fact]
    public async void IntervalExecutionTest()
    {
        var target = new PeriodicaBackgroundJobRunner();
        var testJob = new PeriodicalJobForTest();

        target.Start(1/*run every second*/, testJob);

        await Task.Delay(2500).ContinueWith(c =>
        {
            Assert.Equal(3, testJob.ExecutedCounter);
        });
    }
```

The job for test looks like this:

```
 private class PeriodicalJobForTest : IPeriodicalJob
    {
        public int ExecutedCounter { get; private set; }

        public void Execute(object state)
        {
            this.ExecutedCounter++;
        }
    }
```

So with 2,5 seconds waiting time I expect it to run 3 times, on 0,1 and 2.

In debug the test passes. Build server however fails and says "expected 3, actual 1".

How come? What is different there? Will I also get a problem in production, once it's actually deployed to Azure?

Note: I also tried with Thread.Sleep(), same results.

Just in case the problem might be actually with class under test implementation, the class looks like this:

```
public class PeriodicaBackgroundJobRunner : IPeriodicaBackgroundJobRunner
{
    private Threading.Timer timer;

    public void Start(int interval, IPeriodicalJob job)
    {
        interval = Math.Max(interval, 1) * 1000;

        if (this.timer == null)
        {
            this.timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(job.Execute), null, Timeout.Infinite, interval);
        }

        this.timer.Change(0, interval);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (this.timer != null)
        {
            this.timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem still present, if you change `async void` to `async Task`?

Comment: It does........

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what the problem actually is, but it has something to do with Threading.Timer. Tests worked fine when I rewrote the class without timer:

```
public class PeriodicaBackgroundJobRunner : IPeriodicaBackgroundJobRunner
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;

    public void Start(int interval, IPeriodicalJob job)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            interval = Math.Max(interval, 1) * 1000;

            this.cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            while (true)
            {
                job.Execute(null);
                await Task.Delay(interval, this.cancellationToken.Token);
            }
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (this.cancellationToken != null)
        {
            this.cancellationToken.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```